# How to prove a two-variable function is onto?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I am asked to prove the following two variable function, defined from $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$, is onto:

$$\displaystyle f(m,n) = m-n$$

However, I am not sure how to prove this because I have only done this with a single variable function where we usually chose arbitrarily an x that happens to result in y when we plug it into the function.

One of my friends did in the following way, however, I am not sure if this is correct because it doesn't seem to fit the definition or rigorous enough:

$$\displaystyle \text{Let } x \in \mathbb{Z} \text{ and } n=0$$
$$\displaystyle f(m,0) = m-0 = m$$
$$\displaystyle \text{Thus, $f(m,0)$ has the image of $m$, so the function is onto}$$

Not sure if we can just choose $n=0$ without the need to check other $n$.

Comment: You are only asked to find some $i$ and $j$ such that $f(i,j)=m$. You can certainly take $i=m$ and $j=0$.

Comment: You said Let $x\in\mathbb Z$, but then you didn't use $x$

Comment: Note that "onto" is relative to the *domain* and [codomain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain) of a function, which should be explicitly stated when you define the function $f(x,y)$.

Comment: Defined on what domain?  Onto what codomain?  Without specifying those, the question is not well-defined.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Thanks for the reminder, I forgot to mention those. I will correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether there is **some** pair $(a, b)$ that gets sent to any particular integer $k \in \Bbb Z$. When you show that $(k, 0)$ does in fact get sent there, you are done, even though $(k+1, 1)$ and $(k - 4, -4)$ and lots of others are also sent there. Let other folks use *those* in their own proofs. Yours is done.

Your friend's proof is slightly broken, so it begins with "Let $x \in \Bbb Z$..." but then never mentions $x$ again.

Comment: Thanks a lot! However, something that I don't understand here is that, an onto function means that (correct me if I am wrong) all the elements y in the co-domain have one correspondent x in the domain. $\forall y \in Y$, $\exists x \in X$ | $f(x) = y$. So why here we only need $\textbf{some}$ pair of $(a,b)$

Comment: For each element $y$ in the codomain, there must be *some* element $x$ in the domain with the property that $f(x) = y$. There's nothing that says there must be exactly one; if there were exactly one, then the function would be not just surjective (or "onto") but a bijection  (or "one to one correspondence"). The statement $\exists x : x > 0$ is true, because $1 > 0$, but it's also true because $2 > 0$ and $\pi > 0$ and $1.2324 > 0$.

Comment: oh okay, I understand now. So even though I can prove for other pairs, but it is not necessary. Because by proving f(m,0) has an image of f is already sufficient to conclude that the function is onto.Then I don't have to waste my time trying to explore other ones

Comment: Exactly right!!

Comment: Thanks super a lot! I just couldn't understand this before :)